# C++ linking error while running executable on Yosemite

Tags: c++, osx-yosemite, nlopt

I am trying to compile the example problem given on the website (for C++) and am having an issue: 
NMead.cpp is my program. I compile it using g++

`g++ -g -O2  -I/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include  -L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib -o NMead -lm -lnlopt NMead.cpp -v`

The generated message is:

```
Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++ COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/lto-wrapper Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14 Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc49/gcc49/work/gcc-4.9.3/configure
--prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc49 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc49 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.9 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.9 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --disable-isl-version-check --with-cloog=/opt/local --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc49 4.9.3_0' Thread model: posix gcc version 4.9.3 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.3_0)  COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.5' '-g' '-O2' '-I' '/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include' '-L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib' '-o' 'NMead' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'  /opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/cc1plus -quiet -v
-I /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include -D__DYNAMIC__ NMead.cpp -fPIC -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -quiet -dumpbase NMead.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.10.5 -mtune=core2 -auxbase NMead -g -O2 -version -o /var/folders/zs/t_yzdt597z3cfwlr36hr78gw002vb6/T//cc5WiU5P.s GNU C++ (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.3_0) version 4.9.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin14)  compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version
3.1.3, MPC version 1.0.3 GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072 ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/../../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin14/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:  /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include  /opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/  /opt/local/include/gcc49/c++//x86_64-apple-darwin14  /opt/local/include/gcc49/c++//backward  /opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/include  /opt/local/include  /opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/include-fixed  /usr/include  /System/Library/Frameworks  /Library/Frameworks End of search list. GNU C++ (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.3_0) version 4.9.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin14)   compiled by GNU C version 4.9.3, GMP version
6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.3, MPC version 1.0.3 GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072 Compiler executable checksum: 0ca13fbc9617161ec7a95e943acdf57e COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.5' '-g' '-O2' '-I' '/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include' '-L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib' '-o' 'NMead' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'  /opt/local/bin/as -v -I /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include -arch x86_64
-force_cpusubtype_ALL -o /var/folders/zs/t_yzdt597z3cfwlr36hr78gw002vb6/T//cclPMJVL.o /var/folders/zs/t_yzdt597z3cfwlr36hr78gw002vb6/T//cc5WiU5P.s Apple Inc version cctools-870, GNU assembler version 1.38 COMPILER_PATH=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/:/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/:/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/:/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/:/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/ LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/:/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/../../../:/usr/lib/ COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.5' '-g' '-O2' '-I' '/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/include' '-L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib' '-o' 'NMead' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'  /opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/collect2 -dynamic
-arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.5 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o NMead -L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib
-L/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3 -L/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/../../.. -lnlopt /var/folders/zs/t_yzdt597z3cfwlr36hr78gw002vb6/T//cclPMJVL.o -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v -idsym -dsym collect2 version 4.9.3 /opt/local/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.5 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak
-o NMead -L/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib -L/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3 -L/opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3/../../.. -lnlopt /var/folders/zs/t_yzdt597z3cfwlr36hr78gw002vb6/T//cclPMJVL.o -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-242 configured to support archs: i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6 armv7 armv7s armv7m armv7k arm64 Library search paths:   /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib   /opt/local/lib/gcc49/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/4.9.3    /opt/local/lib/gcc49    /usr/lib    /usr/local/lib Framework search paths:  /Library/Frameworks/    /System/Library/Frameworks/  /opt/local/bin/nm -n /var/folders/zs/t_yzdt597z3cfwlr36hr78gw002vb6/T//cclPMJVL.o dsymutil NMead
```

When I try to run the executable generated:

```
./NMead
```

I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/opt/nlopt/lib/libnlopt_cxx.0.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/dlekshmi/Documents/workspace/TUTORIALS/./NMead   Reason: image
>   not found Trace/BPT trap: 5

I suspected for some reason, it is looking in the wrong place for the library. I ran

```
otool -L ./NMead
```

and the generated messaged indicated that it is indeed:

> ./NMead:
>       /usr/local/opt/nlopt/lib/libnlopt_cxx.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.2.0)
>       /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.21.0)
>       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
>       /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

I am new to C++ and nlopt, am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with your library load path.  The compile and link works because you are specifying the LD path.  I haven't looked at how to adjust this in OS X.  What does `ldd NMead` report?

Comment: From what I know the MacOS does not have an ldd.. and the equivalent to it is what I had typed 'ootool -L ./NMead'. (Ref: http://etymon.blogspot.ch/2009/09/ldd-equivalent-under-darwin-os-x.html)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry.  I meant tool.  And clearly it's still 5 something AM because I didn't even see the output in the question. :)

Comment: Does /usr/local/opt/nlopt/lib/libnlopt_cxx.0.dylib exist?

Comment: Hi again, no it does not... for some reason even if I linked it correctly while compiling, while executing it, it looks into the folder. Since you mentioned about the LD path, I digged a bit more into it and realised, I have to change it for the executable... so I did this: `install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/nlopt/lib/libnlopt_cxx.0.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2/lib/libnlopt_cxx.0.dylib ./NMead`. and now it seems to work.. But I dont understand why this has happened in the first place and if there is a permanent way to fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using the LLVM toolchain or are you doing something that really requires GCC.  It sorta sounds like there's something a bit broken in your home-brew or macports install.